# extracting file name from a link saved

Tags: c#

i have saved a link a database which looks like this

```
~\quizes\314757_499034200123763_1508831626_a.jpg
```

i used the following code to extract the filename

```
Uri uri = new Uri(BulletedList1.DataValueField.ToString());
        string filename=Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
```

but it gives the following error
**The format of the URI could not be determined.**

Comment: Is the `~` character representative of your application root?  What is the value of `BulletedList1.DataValueField.ToString()`?

Comment: and your question is? to find another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx), something like:

```
var dbValue = @"~\quizes\314757_499034200123763_1508831626_a.jpg";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(dbValue);
```

For your example it should work ok.

**Edit**

Just a guess, but if you have all the values from the database read into a BulletList control, you can have a look at the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) property in order to read them. Probably something like:

```
 foreach (var item in BulletedList1.Items)
 {
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(item.ToString());
    // Do stuff with the file name
 }
```

Comment: this is not giving me the value but it just gets the name of the column.

Comment: Updated the code to show how it works. You just need to pass the correct value that you read from the database.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this?

```
var fromDatabase = @"~\quizes\314757_499034200123763_1508831626_a.jpg";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fromDatabase);
```

or do you need to expand the "~" for other reasons? in which case the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx might help you.

Answer (score 0):

i got my work done by using the following.

```
ListItem li = BulletedList1.Items[e.Index];

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(li.Value.ToString());
```